# How to change glyphicon's position with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown and a glyphicon I want to change glyphicon's position on page load.

I want to move it slighter left side from the current position as it is overlapping on dropdown arrow-icon.

It is okay with textboxes.

I have created a jQuery function but its not working from document.ready even its working from browser console.

jQuery:-

```
    $('span.form-control-feedback').each(function () {              
            if ($(this).closest('.at-required').is("select")) {                   
                //alert($(this).attr('class'));
                $(this).css('right', '27px');
            }
        });
```

[image]

HTML:-

```
  <select required="true" class="form-control at-required" title="Please select Department" id="ddlDepartmentName" name="ctl00ddlDepartmentName">
        <option value="- - Select - -">- - Select - -</option>
        <option value="1">.NET</option>
        <option value="2">PHP</option>
       </select>   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
```

Comment: You can't use `closest` to get the `select` element. Use `prev` instead to check if it's the previous sibling

Comment: both functions working yours and mine as well but from console only.

Comment: Does the select and the glyph exist on document ready or is either of them added dynamically afterwards? (Also I don't understand why `closest` works, based on the pasted code it shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(this).css( "padding-right", "27" );`?

Comment: The problem is that its working from browser consol but not working on document.ready

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```html
$('.form-control-feedback').css('margin-right', '20px');
```

The glyphicon's position changed with jQuery

Comment: thanks @Sayed , but I think the problem is that these glyphicon are hidden on page-load that is why jquery not working

Comment: You mean, you are getting issue on page loading...if possible can you show me the demo link where exact you getting problem.

Comment: @  Marco Bonelli, Thanks for your review. I have updated query.